# flutter bloc - wrong state is sent from bloc to widget

Tags: flutter

It seems like bug in bloc v0.11.2

I have the following Event/State:

```
class DeleteReceipt extends ReceiptEvent {
  final Receipt receipt;
  DeleteReceipt(this.receipt) : super([receipt]);
}

class ReceiptDeleted extends ReceiptState {
  final Receipt receipt;
  ReceiptDeleted(this.receipt) : super();
}
```

and the following code in bloc:

```
if (event is DeleteReceipt) {
  var delReceipt = event.receipt;
  await _receiptDao.delete(delReceipt);
  print("deleting: " + delReceipt.snapshot.documentID);
  yield ReceiptDeleted(delReceipt);
}
```

and my widget I have:

```
      if (state is ReceiptDeleted) {
        print("delete: "+state.receipt.snapshot.documentID);
        receipts.delete(state.receipt);
      }
```

and when I do:  `_receiptBloc.dispatch(DeleteReceipt(receipt));`
the first time I get:

```
I/flutter (28196): deleting: AzgAzcn5wRNFVd7NyZqQ
I/flutter (28196): delete: AzgAzcn5wRNFVd7NyZqQ
```

which is correct, but the second time I do `_receiptBloc.dispatch(DeleteReceipt(receipt));` on a different receipt, I get:

```
I/flutter (28196): deleting: d4oUjrGwHX1TvIDr9L2M
I/flutter (28196): delete: AzgAzcn5wRNFVd7NyZqQ
```

You can see that in the second time the `DeleteReceipt` event was received with the correct value, but the `ReceiptDeleted` State was received with the wrong value, and then it just get stuck like this, it never fires `ReceiptDeleted` State with the correct value, only with the first value.

My app is not trivial, and I have set many events and state in the past, and it worked with no issue (except this one, that probably is related [flutter bloc state not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480113/flutter-bloc-state-not-received))

Basically I let the user create photos of receipt, that are persistent (using bloc/firestore), and I want to let the user delete them, so when the user click on a receipt, it opens in a new screen:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return ReceiptDetailPage(widget.receipt);
    },
  ),
```

and when the user click on delete, I show a dialog, and delete the receipt if is `OK`

```
var result = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext dialogCtxt) {
    // return object of type Dialog
    return AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).deleteReceiptQuestion),
      actions: <Widget>[
        // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).cancel),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(dialogCtxt).pop("cancel");
          },
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).ok),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(dialogCtxt).pop("OK");
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
if (result == 'OK') {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  _receiptBloc.dispatch(DeleteReceipt(receipt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

add state/event:

```
class EmptyState extends ReceiptState {}
class EmptyEvent extends ReceiptEvent {}
```

after receiving the delete state do:

```
      if (state is ReceiptDeleted) {
        print("delete: "+state.receipt.snapshot.documentID);
        receipts.delete(state.receipt);
        _receiptBloc.dispatch(EmptyEvent()); // add this line
      }
```

and add this to your bloc

```
if (event is EmptyEvent) {
  yield EmptyState();
}
```

This will cause an empty event and state to be fired and will clear the problem

Explain: I noticed that once I fire a State, the block provider will send that state every time I change a screen, which is strange since the app is receiving a `Delete` State many time. this is not a problem in my case, since the code will try to delete an element that is already delete and will fail quietly:

```
  void delete(Receipt receipt) {
    try {
      Receipt oldReceipt = receipts.firstWhere(
          (r) => r.snapshot.documentID == receipt.snapshot.documentID);
      receipts.remove(oldReceipt);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

NOTE: this seems to happen with all State that the app is firing, not only the `Delete` state

So I guest that if I will fire an empty event, it will clear the old `Delete` state, and will somehow fix the issue, and WALLA...

Note that I didn't had to actually listen to the `EmptyState` any where in my code

MORE INFO:

I realize that although the `bloc` seems to loose state, also my design is wrong, because the Data Structure should be updated in the `bloc`, once the event is received and not in the widget, when the state is received (or not received in this case, which cause the bug)

Initially I used `bloc` with `sembast`, but then I wanted the data to be sync with the remote DB, so I replaced `sembast` with `firestore`.

but that causes the load time to go from nothing, to more than 2 seconds, and that is a problem since in the original design I load all the data from the DB on every update.

So I tried to update the `store` and the UI seperatly, ie. instead of reading all the data, I keep a List in my widget and update the widget when the state changes - per update/delete state.

That was a problem, since many state were lost (especially when the user click fast - which cause many events/states to fire)

So I guess a `correct` solution would be to manage the in-memory Data in a separate Service, and update the Data when the Event is received, and then read all data from the Service instead of the store (when possible)